# grunt: how to replace paths in html file using grunt task

Tags: task, gruntjs

inside my grunt configuration if have a variable which defines a directory which contains a css file. Now I would like to configure a grunt task which insert the value of this variable into a html file.
For example, I can imagine that I have an index.html file as follows

```
<!doctype html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="<% pathToCss %>/styles.css">
      ...
```

But I cannot find a task which can do that for me. Any suggestions which grunt taks can do this for me ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just found out that it can be done with grunt.template as follows:

```
template: {
        options: {
            data: {
                pathToCss: './css'
            }
        },
        demo: {
            files: [
                { '<%= ./output/index.html':  ['<%= ./input/template.html'] }
            ]
        }
    },
```

And in the input file (template.html) you define 'pathToCss' as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../<%- pathToCss %>/styles.css">
```

However, if I look at the [documentation](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.template), I don't see where this is documentated!

Comment: Is this answer reference the tasks grunt-template, which itself uses grunt.template ? Because you can't do this with just grunt.template

Answer (score 7):

I think the [grunt-replace](https://github.com/outaTiME/grunt-replace) package is what you're looking for. You can read an external file and use its value in the `patterns` definitions like so:

```
replace: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      patterns: [
        {
          match: '<% pathToCss %>',
          replacement: '<%= grunt.file.read("conf/assets-dir.txt") %>'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```