# Grunt Task for String Replacement

Tags: javascript, replace, gruntjs, task

I'm searching for a grunt task where I can replace a string in a file with text from another file. e.g.:

**In the Gruntfile:**
-> src: strings.txt / index.html
-> dist: index-replaced.html

**In the strings.txt:**
placeholder-1: lorem ipsum....
placeholder-2: lorem impsum blabla...

**In the Index.html:**
Here comes the placeholder text {{placeholder-1}}

**In the Index-replaced.html:**
Here comes the placeholder text lorem ipsum....


If seen all this tasks where you can specify your replacements in the gruntfile.js, but this doesn't match my needs. So anyone any idea? thx

Comment: possible duplicate of [grunt: how to replace paths in html file using grunt task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20020981/grunt-how-to-replace-paths-in-html-file-using-grunt-task)

Comment: No, i'ts not a possible duplicate. As mentioned above: _If seen all this tasks where you can specify your replacements in the gruntfile.js, but this doesn't match my needs._