# Add string to route of files with grunt

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I'm building an angularJS and i need to add a string to all sources path something like this:

```
<script src="{{STATIC_URL}}scripts/scripts.65cfde8a.js"></script>
```

Is there a way to achieve this using a grunt task?

I'm using Yeoman with the [angular generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular#readme).

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Check this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20020981/grunt-how-to-replace-paths-in-html-file-using-grunt-task). You can do it either by using grunt [templates](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.template) or using [grunt-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-replace) module.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using [grunt-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-replace)

I installed grunt-replace and added this to the gruntfile

```
    replace: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                patterns: [
                    {
                        match: /src="scripts/g,
                        replacement: 'src="{{STATIC_URL}}scripts'
                    },
                    {
                        match: /href="styles/g,
                        replacement: 'href="{{STATIC_URL}}styles'
                    }
                ]
            },
            files: [
                {
                    expand: true, 
                    flatten: true, 
                    src: [
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/index.html',
                    ],
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```