# Changing index.html src attribute value into another value using Grunt

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am trying to modify my project index.html file src into another src.

I have currently

```
<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
```

now i want to convert it into like this

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
```

how can i do this using grunt??

Thanks

Comment: duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20020981/grunt-how-to-replace-paths-in-html-file-using-grunt-task

Comment: @danywalls I think it is not same question. It must be done by other way

Comment: @Kawsar-ahmedI think you want a set a path for each enviroment or place, this  https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-processhtml  package should help you.

Answer (score 0):

@danywalls suggestion is correct.

The plugin [grunt-processhtml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-processhtml) can certainly meet your requirements.

Firstly add that plugin to your `package.json`:

`$ npm install grunt-processhtml --save-dev`

Then add [special comments](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-processhtml#the-processhtml-task) around your `<script>` tags in the source `index.html` as follows:

```html
<!--build:js bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js-->
<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--/build-->

<!--build:js bower_components/angular/angular.min.js-->
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<!--/build-->
```

NOTE: Inside the `<!--build:js ... -->` comment you simply specify the src path that you want your resultant `index.html` to include.

Next add a task similar to this to your `Gruntfile.js`:

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        /* Update script src attribute in .html */
        processhtml: {
            updateScriptLinks: {
                files: {
                    // NOTE: Adjust the paths below according to your project directory structure
                    './dist/index.html': ['./src/index.html'] // destination : source
                }
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-processhtml');

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'processhtml:updateScriptLinks'
    ]);

};
```